# Which is the algorithm to calc possible sets?

Tags: combinatorics

Example: I have a set {a,b,c}.  I want to know how many different sets could I get from these elements. 
-Ex:  {a,b} , {a,c} , {a}, {b} , {c} , {b,c} and {a,b,c} itself

Which is the algorithm ?  and which theory is this?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set with $n$ elements it has $2^n$ subsets, and $2^n-1$ *non-empty* subsets.

You can prove this by induction, in fact this is one of the standard examples for induction.

In your example you have $\{a,b,c\}$ which are $3$ elements, and therefore $2^3-1=7$ non-empty subsets.

Answer (score 1):

You are "computing" the so-called powerset of the initial set. Each element (of the original set) can or cannot be chosen in a possible subset. If you start with $n$ elements that are $n$ yes/no choices, so $2^n$ possible subsets. That includes the all-no sequence of choices, or the emptyset $\varnothing$.

I guess that *is* the algorithm you want to have. If you know binary numbers, listing them is as listing subsets. In your example 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, \dots, 111 form
$\varnothing$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{b,a\}$, $\{c\}$, $\{c,a\}$, $\{c,b\}$, $\{c,b,a\}$. Done. Silly order in the sets, but I wanted to stay close to the order I took for the bits: cab.